# why could we find inverse matrix of n*n by repetitively calculating the determinant?

Tags: matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices

I am using the adjugate matrix.

Say if we want to find the inverse of this matrix:

$A =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}$

we can start from finding the determinant of A and finding their minor.

det(A)= -2

and

M<sub>1,1</sub>=4 ...  M<sub>2,1</sub>=2

M<sub>1,2</sub>=3 ...  M<sub>2,2</sub>=1

we can then put everything together with adjustments to signs and get

A<sup>-1</sup> = 1/-2 *$\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 2 \\
3 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}$

same thing could be say for the 3x3 matrix or higher(n*n)

for 3x3 matrix

A<sup>-1</sup> = 1/det(A)*$\begin{bmatrix} a & d & g\\
b & e & h\\ c & f & i
\end{bmatrix}$

where a to g is the minor of matrix A and sign adjusted as appropriate.

for example a would be the minor of cell (1,1) and don't need to change sign

b would be the minor of cell (1,2) and need to change sign (multiply by -1)

and minor is basically the determinant of the smaller portion of the entire matrix.

My question:
I wonder why this method works. I only know that determinant describe how the identity matrix is being stretch to this new matrix A. why calculating this rate of stretching for many smaller part of the matrix would help us find the inverse. and how to adjust the sign in any n*n matrix. Why do we need to multiply some minor by -1?

Comment: This is a classical theorem, which is explained in [Matrix Inverse by Cofactors](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~jmckinno/Math106/Week11/Lecture4j.pdf) paper. Or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6APsIqyx-k).

Comment: Thus is sometimes called the Laplace expansion of the determinant. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion